# Url max length when using rest (jersey)

Tags: java, javascript, rest, url, jersey

if I ask a (rest) service to give me data with an url like this

`http://example.com/?userid=1,2,3,4(...)`

there's a url size limit, meaning I am limited in how many userids I can send over to the server.

So far so clear, but if I call this url from a jersey client to a jersy rest service, it seems like I have no limit. So is there a url limit for jersey as well?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The limit would be defined by your servlet container. For example, this describes setting the [limit in tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

The limit comes from the http servlet container configuration or http client, **not from the rest framework** as also mentioned in the above response. In case of jetty http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html -> HTTP Configuration -> requestHeaderSize