# Does the Neo4j webserver have a maximum url lenght for GET queries?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, jersey

I'm using jersey to make a call to an unmanaged extension which receives params, and when i put thousands (extreme but possible use case) it gives the following exception:

`javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server`

Just when I make the call `Response resp = invocationBuilder.get();`

Is there a limit in the URL length on the neo4j webserver? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157082/url-max-length-when-using-rest-jersey) that jersey doesn't have a limit.

More info on the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:625)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:637)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1321)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
```

[Here is a txt file with the query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oet3iu898g27h5m/query10000.txt?dl=0) I'm making to the unmanaged extension endpoint.

Comment: what does the server says?

Comment: The `http.log` do not show the GET query

Comment: I don't know if the GET query never reach the web server, or if it does and it rejects it

Comment: I think it's rather in your http library / the http protocol. What is the actual request you send?

Comment: I added a link to a query example

Answer (score 0):

A request of 186KB (your file) seems really big to me. Jetty comes per default with 8K (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html -> HTTP Configuration -> requestHeaderSize). If you are using another servlet container just look for something similar.

I do not know if it is possible to change it in neo4j. I would try with smaller queries.

Comment: Usually, a request shouldn't be that large. But that query is a "possible" even if extreme example, that's why I was asking about the neo4j webservice max request size.

Comment: If you look into neo4j libs ($NEO_HOME/system/lib) you will find several jetty jars, so I understand neo4j runs on jetty. That's the reason why I am mentioning jetty. On the other hand, that the spec does not specify a max length does not implies that a limit shouldn't exist (indeed it must always exist). So for such an atypical query length, is mostly sure taht you need to update the http servlet configuration

Comment: I didn't realized neo4j run on jetty. Any idea where can i find the servlet configuration? I bet it is in (conf/neo4j-server.properties) but haven't be able to find what possible config values can I set except for the ones are there already.